# Python Pipes - What Happens When Reading Output Incrementally

Tags: python, unix, pipe

According to [a section](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/book015.html#toc159) in [this presumably accurate book](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/),

> A common use of pipes is to read a
>   compressed file incrementally; that
>   is, without uncompressing the whole
>   thing at once. The following function
>   takes the name of a compressed file as
>   a parameter and returns a pipe that
>   uses gunzip to decompress the
>   contents:
>
> ```
>  def open_gunzip(filename):
>      cmd = 'gunzip -c ' + filename
>      fp = os.popen(cmd)
>      return fp
> ```
>
> If you read lines from fp one at a
>   time, **you never have to store the
>   uncompressed file in memory or on
>   disk.**

Maybe I'm just interpreting this wrong, but I don't see how this is possible.  Python couldn't have any means of pausing gunzip halfway through spitting out the results, right?  I assume gunzip isn't going to block until a line of output is read before continuing to output more lines, so some buffer has to be capturing all of this (whether inside the Python interpreter or in the OS, whether in memory or on disk), meaning the uncompressed file is being stored **somewhere** in full...right?

Comment: Never use `os.popen`. It is deprecated. Use the `subprocess` module instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is faulty.  gunzip does not have to see the entire file to unzip it.  Read the unzip file format.  There's a directory, with offsets to the individual components.

It's possible to unzip a file in pieces.

"uncompressed file is being stored somewhere in full...right?"

Not necessarily.  Not sure why you're assuming it or where you read it.

All low-level I/O calls can block.  The write in gunzip -- when writing to a pipe -- can block when the pipe buffer is full.  That's the way I/O to a pipe is defined.  Pipe I/O blocks.

Check the man pages for pipe for details.

> If a process attempts to read from an
>   empty  pipe,  then  read(2)  will
>   block  until  data  is  available.  If
>   a process attempts to write to a
>   full pipe (see below), then write(2)
>   blocks until sufficient  data  has
>   been  read  from the pipe to allow the
>   write to complete.  Non-blocking
>   I/O is possible by using the fcntl(2)
>   F_SETFL operation to  enable  the
>   O_NONBLOCK open file status flag.

Answer (score 1):

This really comes from `gunzip` implementation, not from python.
It is written in C. It probably uses `fwrite()` from C's `stdio.h` to write its output.

`libc6` implementation I use automatically creates an output buffer, and when it is filled, blocks on `fwrite()` until it can write more.

Comment: The key point is that the blocking happens in the kernel when `gunzip` calls `write()`. This happens regardless of whether your program is written in C or in Python or is even using libc at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Python that is suspending `gunzip`, it's that the kernel will stop executing `gunzip` when it tries writing (using the `write()` syscall) to a full buffer. This is called **blocking on IO**. The kernel maintains an internal buffer connecting the two ends of the pipline, independent of any buffering happening in any processes that are writing to or reading from the pipe.

Python will similarly block when reading from a pipe that has an empty buffer i.e. that doesn't currently have any data from `gunzip` written to it.

Pipes can be seen as as solution to the [Producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).